# Approach to be consider to run two different version of angular(angular 1 older version and new angular 6)in single application

Tags: vmware-clarity

Initially our project was build in angular1 which is older version, now we have got new requirement for the same project which we want to write in angular 6.

We dont want rewrite the existing angular1 project but for new enhancement  we want to write in latest version of angular.

So looking for the solution to run two different version of angular in single application.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[ngUpgrade](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)**:
From the docs:

> The ngUpgrade library in Angular is a very useful tool for upgrading anything but the smallest of applications. With it you can mix and match AngularJS and Angular components in the same application and have them interoperate seamlessly. That means you don't have to do the upgrade work all at once, since there's a natural coexistence between the two frameworks during the transition period.